# Find $\displaystyle \int_0^1x^a \ln(x)^m \mathrm{d}x$

Tags: calculus, integration

Find $$\int_0^1x^a \ln(x)^m\ \mathrm{d}x$$ where $a>-1$ and $m$ is a nonnegative integer. I did a subsitiution and changed this into a multiple of the gamma function. I get $(-1)^m m! e^a$ as the solution but Mathematica does not agree with me. Can someone confirm my answer or provide a solution?

Comment: What was your substitution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I get

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 x^a (\ln x)^m\,dx &= \int_0^\infty e^{-at} (-t)^m e^{-t}\,dt\tag{$x = e^{-t}$}\\
&= (-1)^m \int_0^\infty t^m e^{-(a+1)t}\,dt\\
&= \frac{(-1)^m}{(a+1)^{m+1}} \int_0^\infty u^m e^{-u}\,du \tag{$u=(a+1)t$}\\
&= \frac{(-1)^m m!}{(a+1)^{m+1}}.
\end{align}$$

Does that agree with Mathematica's result?

Comment: Yea that's it, I made a simple error.

Answer (score 5):

Let $F(a,m)$ the given integral. By integration by parts we have

$$F(a,m)=-\frac{m}{a+1}\int_0^1x^{a}\ln(x)^{m-1}dx=-\frac{m}{a+1}F(a,m-1)$$
and by simple induction we get
$$F(a,m)=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(a+1)^m}F(a,0)=\frac{(-1)^mm!}{(a+1)^{m+1}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
&\color{#0000ff}{\large\int_{0}^{1}x^{a}\ln^{m}\pars{x}\,\dd x}
= \lim_{\mu \to 0^{+}}\totald[m]{}{\mu}\int_{0}^{1}x^{a}x^{\mu}\,\dd x
=\lim_{\mu \to 0^{+}}\totald[m]{}{\mu}\bracks{1 \over \mu + a + 1}
\\[3mm]&=\lim_{\mu \to 0^{+}}\bracks{\pars{-1}^{m}\,m! \over \pars{\mu + a + 1}^{m + 1}}
=\color{#0000ff}{\large%
{\pars{-1}^{m}\,m! \over \pars{a + 1}^{m + 1}}}
\end{align}

Comment: i dont quite follow the first step, how?

Comment: @Lost1 $\displaystyle{\large {{\rm d}x^{\mu} \over {\rm d}\mu} = x^{\mu}\ln\left(x\right)}$. If you repeat it $\displaystyle{\large m}$-times you get $\displaystyle{\large  x^{\mu}\ln^{m}\left(x\right)}$. The final limit purpose is 'to kill' the $\displaystyle{\large x^{\mu}}$ factor.

Comment: oh dear, sorry! this is so elementary... nice method... and oh btw, you mean $d/d\mu$ in the comment, i was thinking $d/dx$, that is why i am confused. learn something new everyday...